# How to separate parameters with same name from json

Tags: java, json, string

I know that here is so many questions with String to JsonObject conversion but I cant find working solution. I am using java 17. I would like to get data from an API and split these two value into two separate parameters. I have a problem with both values ​​having the same name and they are in the same array. Here is my JSON and code

```
{
"name": "Fear and Greed Index",
"data": [
    {
        "value": "49",
        "value_classification": "Neutral",
        "timestamp": "1633219200",
        "time_until_update": "37615"
    },
    {
        "value": "54",
        "value_classification": "Neutral",
        "timestamp": "1633132800"
    }
],
"metadata": {
    "error": null
}
```

}

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
private static final String FANG_URL = "https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=2";

public FangDto getFangFromLastTwoDays() throws ParseException {
    String response = restTemplate.getForObject(FANG_URL, String.class);

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response);

    Object z = jsonObj.get("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there

You need to get the array out first, and then you can access those values

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
for( int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
 long yourAnswer = jsonArray.get(i).getLong("value");
}
```

Keep in mind that `yourAnswer` variable is in a loop, use it as you see fit.

Comment: I have a problem. Cannot resolve method 'getJsonArray' in 'JSONObject'

Comment: which library are you using for JSON parsing? is it `org.json` or `org.simple.json` ?

Comment: import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;

Comment: should have added that in the question  sorry, this solution would work for `org.json` library, if it's possible for you to change it, otherwise, need to search the docs for those